# How to delete subscriptions on ogone

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have implemented code for recurrent payment (subscription) using Direct link. From my site, I am able to create subscriptions.

But I am unable to delete subscriptions.

Can anyone please tell me how I can delete subscriptions from my site on ogone. (Rails project)

Thank you.

Comment: Could you share relevant code of what you have so far?

Comment: @Dave Powers - Hi thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Dave Powers - 
Presently I am trying to delete subscription using Batch with operation "DEL"


"SHASign"=>"XXXXXXXX"
"OPERATION"=>"DEL"
"PSWD"=>"XXXXXXX"
"USERID"=>"testpayment"
"PROCESS_MODE"=>"CHECKANDPROCESS"
"PSPID"=>"XXXXXXX"
"FILE"=>"DELSUBS;;;;;pspid;subscription_id;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"
"TRANSACTION_CODE"=>"MTR"
"FILE_REFERENCE=>"1a"
"PAYID=>"44687939"
"NB_PAYMENTS"=>"1"
"SUB_AMOUNT"=>nil
"SUBSCRIPTION_ID"=>"test1232"
"REPLY_TYPE=>"XML"
MODE=>"SYNC"



But I am unable to get response from ogone. Please correct me.

Comment: Is it possible to delete subscription using Direct link?